# How to Get distance time and class through OpenstreetmapX?

Tags: julia, openstreetmap

I've been trying to query some edge information from an exported network from Openstreet map via this package [OpenstreetmapX.jl](https://github.com/pszufe/OpenStreetMapX.jl) . However, it appears that some functionality are not directly available. For instance:

Suppose you have a set of links in the form of `Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}`  and you wish to identify their distance, travel time, and class type. I know for the distance you can call something like the following command:

```
Links = [(301972446, 60649731)
 (60649731, 301972446)
 (2505989518, 2489651510)
 (2489651510, 60649731)
 (60649731, 301972503)
 (267224410, 2895172669)
 (2895172669, 267224410)
 (582794232, 582794289)]

# for example to know the distance of the first edge in Link set

distance(map.nodes[links[1][1]],map.nodes[links[1][2]] )
```

But this is not efficient. Is there anything that directly return the distance, time, and class of each edges? Like:

```
distance( (582794232, 582794289))
distance( links[1])
time(links[1])
class(links[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to access the MapData struct (type `?MapData` for details).

#### Edges

Suppose you have a map:

```
using OpenStreetMapX
m = get_map_data(joinpath(dirname(pathof(OpenStreetMapX)),"..","test/data/reno_east3.osm");use_cache=false);
```

All edges are just a Vector

```
julia> links = m.e[1:2]   # sample 2 edges on map
2-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (2441017888, 2975020216)
 (139988738, 385046328)
```

#### Edge classes

Edge classes are also a vector so for the above example you could do `m.class[1:2]`. Or you could search the id on the edge list:

```
 m.class[findfirst(==((140044645, 140044632)), m.e)]
```

This yields class number - for translation to class name use `OpenStreetMapX.ROAD_CLASSES`

#### Edge lenghts

The distances are available in `w` matrix, so you can do:

```
julia> m.w[m.v[140044645], m.v[140044632]]
41.239883456012905
```

You can also recalculate it using `distance` function:

```
julia> distance(m.nodes, [(140044645, 140044632)])
1-element Vector{Float64}:
 40.99997118352562
```

You might notice that this value is slightly lower as the `distance` function just calculates a stright line distance. However the `get_map_data` function when parsing the map, by default compresses irrelevant edges (the parameter `only_intersections=true`), and the distances in `w` are calculated before compression. In other words `w` includes curvature of the road and `distance` is just a straight line.

#### Travel times

You can get the travel times for edges at once:

```
julia> OpenStreetMapX.network_travel_times(m)
4220-element Vector{Float64}:
  1.5857447369115734
  2.3649894625077863
 ...
```

#### Routing

Finally, you can use A-star algorithm to find a distance between any two nodes:

```
julia> shortest_route(m, 140044645, 140044632)
([140044645, 140044632], 41.239883456012905, 1.4846358044164647)
```

The returned tuple contains:

- the shortest route (nodes)
- the distance in meters
- the driving time in seconds

Comment: Hi @Przemyslaw Szufel THANKS A LOT for this complete answer!  Could you help with this one also? For the travel time you mentioned that we can get it at once. If we just want to know some of them; Is it possible to query? For example I only want to know the travel time of this edge `(140044645, 140044632)`. How to understand??

Comment: `travelT = 3.6 * edge_len_w  / OpenStreetMapX.SPEED_ROADS_URBAN[edge_class]`

Comment: Why when I try this one, it returns error!  `(140044645, 140044632)` is an edge. Right? So, why can't return its class and instead error

Comment: perhaps you made a typo? all codes from this post work.